# SQL: Split a single row into 2 or 3 rows

Tags: sql, unpivot

I'm looking to split a row into 2 or 3 rows. Is this possible?
I have a table that shows quotes like this:

TABLE NAME: **Quotes**

```
ID | NAME  | BusCost | TaxiCost | TrainCost 
-------------------------------------------
01 | Steve | NULL    | 25       | NULL
02 | Barry | 15      | 30       | NULL
03 | Bob   | 150     | 400      | 300
```

But I want to show the quotes like this:

```
ID | Name   | Cost
------------------
01 | Steve  | 25
02 | Barry  | 15
02 | Barry  | 30
03 | Bob    | 30
03 | Bob    | 100
03 | Bob    | 70
```

I am guessing I am going to need to use some kind of `UNION` to do this but I'm at a loss. I'm relatively new to SQL and was hoping if anyone can point in me in the right direction.

The closest I've come (not very close either) is by doing this:

```
SELECT COST
FROM 
(
SELECT BusCost AS COST FROM Quotes
UNION
SELECT TaxiCost AS COST FROM Quotes
UNION
SELECT TrainCost AS COST FROM Quotes
) A
GROUP BY COST

SELECT id, name FROM Quotes
UNION ALL
SELECT COST
FROM
(
SELECT BusCost AS COST FROM Quotes
UNION
SELECT TaxiCost AS COST FROM Quotes
UNION
SELECT TrainCost AS COST FROM Quotes
) A
GROUP BY COST
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates, so if Bob spend 30 on a busride and Steve 30 on a trainride, you end up with only one entry of `30`. To keep duplicates, use `UNION ALL`. You also might want to take a look at `PIVOT`

Comment: Your desired results for Bob don't appear to match the input data. Is there some special math going on, or is it just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        ,       Name
        ,       BusCost as Cost
        FROM    Quotes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id
        ,       Name
        ,       TaxiCost
        FROM    Quotes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id
        ,       Name
        ,       TrainCost
        FROM    Quotes
        ) AllCosts
WHERE   Cost IS NOT NULL
```

The `where` clause removes rows that have no cost, for example when `TaxiCost` is empty.  Use `union all` instead of `union`: the later removes duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked a treat!